# Resample after rolling mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a timeseries dataframe with a column `volt`. I have applied rolling window operation on this dataframe with wondow of 24H. The code to rolling window is

```
telemetry['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(telemetry['datetime'])

a = telemetry.set_index('datetime').groupby('machineID').rolling(window=1, freq='24h').mean()['volt']
```

and the dataframe looks like this after rolling mean

```
machineID  datetime           
1          2015-01-01 06:00:00    151.919999
           2015-01-01 07:00:00    174.522001
           2015-01-01 08:00:00    146.912822
           2015-01-01 09:00:00    179.530561
           2015-01-01 10:00:00    180.544277
                                     ...    
1000       2016-01-01 02:00:00    174.076779
           2016-01-01 03:00:00    130.151378
           2016-01-01 04:00:00    140.423844
           2016-01-01 05:00:00    160.007424
           2016-01-01 06:00:00    164.590354
Name: volt, Length: 8761000, dtype: float64
```

The last column is mean of volt.

Now I want to apply resampling for 12H frequency on `datetime` column.

```
a = a.resample('12H', on='datetime')
```

But get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-d1e27c8b07ce> in <module>
----> 1 a = a.resample('12h', on='datetime')

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base, on, level)
   8447             base=base,
   8448             key=on,
-> 8449             level=level,
   8450         )
   8451         return _maybe_process_deprecations(

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in resample(obj, kind, **kwds)
   1304     """
   1305     tg = TimeGrouper(**kwds)
-> 1306     return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
   1307 
   1308 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in _get_resampler(self, obj, kind)
   1428 
   1429         """
-> 1430         self._set_grouper(obj)
   1431 
   1432         ax = self.ax

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in _set_grouper(self, obj, sort)
    171             else:
    172                 if key not in obj._info_axis:
--> 173                     raise KeyError("The grouper name {0} is not found".format(key))
    174                 ax = Index(obj[key], name=key)
    175 

KeyError: 'The grouper name datetime is not found'
```

I am not getting how to apply resampling after rolling window mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `level` instead `on` and add aggregate function:

```
a = a.resample('12H', level='datetime').mean()
```

EDIT:

```
a = (telemetry.set_index('datetime')
              .groupby('machineID')
              .rolling(window=1, freq='24h')['volt']
              .mean())


b = a.groupby(['machineID', pd.Grouper(freq='12H', level='datetime')]).mean()
```

Comment: But in the topmost dataframe, you can see there are 1-1000 MachineIDs and your code snippet gives mean for just 1 machineID. How to get resampled mean for 1000 MachineIDs

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar - If need per `machineID` added to `EDIT`

Comment: In `b` where you have used `freq=12H`, it is giving an error `ValueError: window must be an integer`

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar - hmm, `window=1,` cannot be used there?

Comment: no window=1 is working. But in second part of your code snippet `b` there is `rolling(freq='12H'` which is not working. Strange because in `a` it is working

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar - testing.

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar - answer was edited.

Comment: Worked, thanks! Please upvote the question.